# 301 Redirect to single url without autosubstitution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I need to redirect site's visitors from `/good/cats` to `/bad`. What i write:

```
Redirect 301 /good/cats http://somedomain/bad
```

What i get:

```
http://somedomain/bad/cats
```

What should i write to redirect to the `http://somedomain/bad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/good/cats$  http://somedomain/bad
```

The reason why your Redirect is not working is because `Redirect` directive appends additional old path segments to the destination. so the `/cats` is being appened.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!